# How to iterate through a HashMap in parallel in Rust?

Tags: rust, rayon

I have a `HashMap` and want to iterate through its values in parallel using `rayon`. I cannot consume it and it is not feasible to first create a `Vec` from the values.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: What about wrapping the HashMap into a `Arc` and passing that to rayon?

Comment: Ok, how would you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Rayon [implements `IntoParallelIterator` for `&HashMap`](https://docs.rs/rayon/latest/rayon/iter/trait.IntoParallelIterator.html#impl-IntoParallelIterator-for-%26%27a+HashMap%3CK,+V,+S%3E).

So you can just call `par_iter` on the hashmap with rayon's prelude imported and it'll work: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e710e23bcc99bd09ce4fab5ba7544604

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let h = HashMap::from([
        ("foo", 1),
        ("bar", 2),
        ("baz", 3),
        ("qux", 4),
        ("quux", 5),
    ]);
    thing(&h);
}

fn thing(m: &HashMap<&str, usize>) {
    let v: usize = m.par_iter()
        .map(|(_, v)| *v)
        .sum();
    println!("{}", v);
}
```